# Why is my recursive function returning a None value

Tags: python, recursion

The function takes a string value and recursively checks the length of number and breaks if it detects a space, returning the full number.

```
def detectNumber(stringVal,lp,makeNumber=""):
    try:
        if stringVal[lp] == " ":
        
            print("Space detected")
            
            print(f"At start makeNumber was {makeNumber}")
            return makeNumber
            
        else:
            makeNumber +=stringVal[lp]
            lp +=1
            detectNumber(stringVal, lp,makeNumber= makeNumber)
        
    except:
        print(f"Error {lp}")
```

Event though the print statement shows the correct value of makeNumber when i return that value it always reverts to None. Why?

Example input

```
detectNumber("12456  18",0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you go down the call stack, you need to be returning values back up the stack once you hit the base case.

```py
def detectNumber(stringVal, lp, makeNumber=""):
    try:
        if stringVal[lp] == " ":

            print("Space detected")

            print(f"At start makeNumber was {makeNumber}")
            return makeNumber

        else:
            makeNumber += stringVal[lp]
            lp += 1
            # Here
            return detectNumber(stringVal, lp, makeNumber=makeNumber)

    except:
        print(f"Error {lp}")
```

```py
>>> detectNumber('123 ', 0)
Space detected
At start makeNumber was 123
'123'
```

You were getting `None`, because the value was only returned to the last recursive caller, rather than all the way back up the stack